# How to extract data from text file and output to web page table

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropdown

Basically I want to create a table of two rows and 4 columns. In the first column I want to be able to select something with a drop down. Once selected the data associated with that selection will be outputted to the other 3 columns in the table. I am new to this so please understand.

I have shown with x,y,z where I want my data values to be displayed. The data will be extracted from a text file. So for example, if I select rose, then the temperature, humidity, and moisture will be shown where x,y,z is respectively.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
      }

      td,
      th {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
      }

      tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #dddddd;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <h2>HTML Table</h2>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Select Plant</th>
        <th>Temp</th>
        <th>Humidity</th>
        <th>Moisture</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="daisy">daisy
    <option value="tulip">tulip
    <option value="rose">rose
    <option value="sunflower">sunflower

</select>


          <p id="demo"></p>


          <script>
            function myFunction() {
              var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
            }

          </script>

          <td>x</td>
          <td>y</td>
          <td>z</td>

      </tr>


    </table>

  </body>

</html>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agk9borw/)

Comment: Which data you want show instead of X,Y,Z

Comment: the data would  be for temperature, moisture, and humidity . So for example 72, 50%, and 68%

Comment: As per your question you said data will be extracted from a text file. so you already got these value right. now you have assign those value to td. For that you can dynamically add tr and td with the value as text

Comment: Well the data would change depending on what option is selected. Also to add a larger number of data it more suitable for the data to be extracted from a text file. Each flower will have its own unique values.

Answer (score 0):

You can slightly improve your HTML first:

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction(this)">
    <option value="">Select a flower...</option>
    <option value="X1,Y1,Z1">daisy</option>
    <option value="X2,Y2,Z2">tulip</option>
    <option value="X3,Y3,Z3">rose</option>
    <option value="X4,Y4,Z4">sunflower</option>
</select>
```

Close the tags for the sake of HTML standard compliance and add "this" pointer to avoid hardcoded ID in JS function (it lets you re-use the function for several elements.

Add dummy first element "Select a flower..." because onchange won't fire at page reload and you can miss the initial value in the data table.

Put the data from the file into the "value" attribute. Note, that if the file size is big you should design a different approach - something that involves paging etc.

in JavaScript:

```
function myFunction(element) {
    var xyz = element.value;
    var flowerName = element.options[element.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    // Parse xyz (in this example in is a string "X,Y,Z"
    // Maybe, parse/format flowerName too
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + flowerName ;
    document.getElementById("demo-values").innerHTML = "The data: " + xyz;
 }
```

Comment: How do I get to change the data values in the tables when selecting an option. For example, I also want to show x1,y1,z1 in the table when selecting "daisy" and so on.

Comment: Well, "Parse xyz" (which shold be converted to an actual code, which depends on your data) and code like "document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + flowerName" (which depends on your tables structure) do the job.

Comment: I’m sorry I’m new to this, could you maybe show the code along with your explanation. It would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you can I will suggest you to put your data in a JSON file, if you are not familiar with this format: https://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_json_intro.asp

It would be easier to get the data direct in the JS, dans display it on the HTML page.

After reading the about the JSON, and if it's not possible tell me!

Comment: I like the idea of using JSON. I am having trouble with having the data displayed in the correct position of the table.

Comment: Did you create your JSON file? You could improve your HTML by giving each <td> an id. Maybe show me what you improve on your code.